# Using xpath to loop over all <h2> tags within a speciifc div

Tags: python, xpath

I am trying to loop over every `<h2>` tag (get the text of it) that is inside div's with the `id="somediv"` using this code:

```
for k,div1 in enumerate(tree.xpath('//div[@id="someid"]')):
  print div1.xpath('.//h2['+str(k+1)+']/text()')
```

but it doesn't work. Why? However this works:

```
for i in range(5): #let's say there are 5 div's with id="someid" to make things easier
  print tree.xpath('//div[@id="someid"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/h2['+str(i)+']/text()'))
```

Problem here is, that I have to give the absolute path `.../div/div[1]/div[2]...` which I don't want. My first solution looks nice but is not producing the desired result, instead I can only retrieve all `<h2>` tags from one `div="someid"` at a time. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: doesn't work how?

Comment: first code returns empty lists

Comment: `//h2` vs `//h` in the second example ?

Comment: corrected to h2

Comment: Have you considered using beautiful soup? I makes parsing HTML extremely easy and this would be a trivial problem.  https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: you're right. still trying to make it work with xpath first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.//` will continue the search down the tree. A list of h2 text nodes subordinate to your div is just

```
tree.xpath('//div[@id="someid"]/.//h2/text()'))
```